# javascript in zend_Form_Element_Text

Tags: zend-framework

I have an autocompexion app. that works. Server side written in php (search.php)
. Client side in javascript (autocomplexion.js).
In a text field this helps to enter town name by giving towns names that starts with the same letters that are entered in the field.
search.php sort a list of towns in towns.txt and choose the ones that match.
autocomplexion.js helps to select among those proposed towns.

My issue :

In Zend i would use this in a form (zend_Form) in a text field created with Zend_Form_Element_Text.
How do i link this field with autocomplexion.js and search.php.
where do i put search.php and autocomplexion.js

Thanks for your answer

Patrick

Answer (score 0):

Write the PHP search function in an Action in an appropriate controller. Point the JS to this action and I think you are done.